# Azure Resource Manager - Creation and Deploying template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Using Visual Studio I am trying to create new project of resource group to create VM.
I am getting below error:

```
Invalid Template
```

Also with some changes I was able to get rid of this error. Now looking to mention VM Size and VM Storage details.

Below is the ARM template sample I am using:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0",
"parameters":{},
"variables":{},
"functions":[],
"resources": [],
"outputs":{}
}
```

Comment: hello @Dhari ,could you  please add the complete code you are using in the template ? can you please provide what you are using in the resources and parameters and any error screenshots which you are receiving while deploying the template. so that we can reproduce the issue using same template and provide solutions.

Comment: `Also with some changes I was able to get rid of this error.` so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid template error occurs during the deployment or testing the template.

Follow the below steps to successfully deploy the template:

1. Create Azure Resource project in VS Code.
2. Select the ARM template as Windows Virtual Machine.
3. Add all the information on parameters and resources tags.
4. Below is the ARM template block for deploying the VM:

   ```
    "name": "windowsVM1",    
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",        
    "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",     
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",       
    "dependsOn": [      
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', toLower('windowsVM1storage'))]",      
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', 'windowsVM1-NetworkInterface')]"        
    ],      
    "tags": {       
    "displayName": "windowsVM1"     
    },      
    "properties": {     
    "hardwareProfile": {        
    "vmSize": "Standard_A2_v2"      
    },      
    "osProfile": {      
    "computerName": "windowsVM1",       
    "adminUsername": "adminUsername",       
    "adminPassword": "adminPassword"        
    },      
    "storageProfile": {     
    "imageReference": {     
    "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",      
    "offer": "WindowsServer",       
    "sku": "2012-R2-Datacenter",        
    "version": "latest"     
    },      
    "osDisk": {     
    "name": "windowsVM1OSDisk",     
    "caching": "ReadWrite",     
    "createOption": "FromImage"     
    }       
    },
   ```
5. Configure the deployment by adding new template.
6. Below are few tags in template where we can specify VM-Size, Storage Name, Network name.

   ```
    "vmSize": "Standard_A2"
    "vhdStorageName": "[concat('vhdstorage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
    "virtualNetworkName": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]"
   ```

Refer to this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-invalid-template?tabs=bicep) in resolving and troubleshooting Invalid template error